# How long will rabies viruses remain alive in human body after an infected person receive the full series of vaccinations and treatment?

Tags: vaccination, virus, disease-transmission, rabies

Will the rabies viruses eventually be exterminated from an infected individual after the full vaccination/treatment series? Otherwise will it remain in the human body forever despite vaccination?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What have you found online about this so far? Often a vaccine won't "exterminate" the virus from you if you're already infected (this is the case for the HPV vaccine for example).

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?